# Format the data read from the sql query in powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, hashtable

I was trying to format the data read from my query.
The data's are sorted in lines and I need it in a table format

```
$objdataset = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "select ord,ord_i,ORD_PRCS from F_ord 
where ord_i in ($ord1);" -server $($SQLServer) -Database $($SQLDBName)



foreach($item  in $objdataset)
{
"ID" +$item.ord 
"order " +$item.ord_i
"pro"+$item.ORD_PRCS
}
```

So how I can format it like

```
ID Order pro
123 ff   Done
145 dd   Progress
567 cc   Done
```

Please help me with this..

Comment: `select ord AS ID,ord_i AS order,ORD_PRCS AS pro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do any special formatting yourself. Printing `$objdataset` should give you a table format automatically, but you can force it with `$objdataset | Format-table -autosize`